# YubiKey 5C is not recognized via a docking station

Tags: yubikey

I have a new [YubiKey 5C NFC](https://www.yubico.com/products/identifying-your-yubikey/) which, when plugged directly in my laptop, works fine. However, when I plug it into my docking station it doesn't work at all.

OS: [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) 20.1 
Kernel: 5.4.0-77-generic 
Docking station: Caldigit ts3

Looking at the [dmesg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmesg) logs, I get the following when plugging the YubiKey into the laptop directly:

```
[  +7.595200] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.149581] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1050, idProduct=0407, bcdDevice= 5.27
[  +0.000005] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  +0.000004] usb 1-1: Product: YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID
[  +0.000002] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Yubico
[  +0.004996] input: Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:1050:0407.00CE/input/input266
[  +0.058128] hid-generic 0003:1050:0407.00CE: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[  +0.001093] hid-generic 0003:1050:0407.00CF: hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Device [Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1
```

When I plug it into the docking station there isn’t anything logged at all (I've tried all USB-C ports on the dock).

Why isn't the YubiKey recognized by the dock?

Comment: Downvoter, what's wrong with this question?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Why are you editing questions and adding content, such as links that didn't previously exist? If an author already linked that's one thing, but content not previously existing shouldn't be added by someone other than the OP _(folks can use a search engine if unfamiliar with a word/device/etc.)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem. The device was not authorized, so the following steps using [boltctl](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/bolt/boltctl.1.en) resolved the issue:

```
boltctl
```

Output:

```
 ● CalDigit, Inc. TS3 Plus
   ├─ type:          peripheral
   ├─ name:          TS3 Plus
   ├─ vendor:        CalDigit, Inc.
   ├─ uuid:          00b81a88-c99c-3d00-ffff-ffffffffffff
   ├─ status:        authorized
   │  ├─ domain:     ca030000-0072-7088-2050-e809e8222120
   │  └─ authflags:  none
   ├─ authorized:    Thu Jul  8 10:17:26 2021
   ├─ connected:     Thu Jul  8 10:01:33 2021
   └─ stored:        no
```

Note the UUID, and then run

```
boltctl authorize 00b81a88-c99c-3d00-ffff-ffffffffffff
```

The YubiKey works just fine now via the dock!

Comment: "boltctl - control the thunderbolt device manager". How is YubiKey related to [Thunderbolt 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)#Thunderbolt_3)?

Answer (score 1):

In the post
[Yubikey is not recognized right after boot](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/5614),
a method to force the detection of the YubiKey was to enter the command:

```
sudo udevadm trigger
```

If this doesn't work for you, Yubico in the post
[Using a YubiKey with USB-C Adapters](https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016614860-Using-a-YubiKey-with-USB-C-Adapters)
acknowledges that some adapters are just incompatible with its
hardware. Yubico doesn't offer any solution to this incompatibility,
except the advice to assure that the adapter is compatible before
buying one.